# Can't figure out what's wrong- must be simple- RSA Encryption Python3

Tags: python, math, encoding, cryptography, rsa

So I'm writing an RSA script for my math class and I'm stuck on the last step of the key generation- encrypting and decryption. I have the following code:

```
print(mulinv(public_e, totient))
lip = (egcd2(public_e, totient))
lip = list(lip)
dhi = 0
print(lip)
if lip[0] < 0:
    dhi = dhi + lip[0] + totient
else:
    dhi = dhi + lip[0]

print(dhi)

again = prime_1 * prime_2
again_2 = (prime_1 - 1) * (prime_2 - 1)
a = 97
enc = pow(a, public_e, again)
print(enc)
dlo = pow(enc, dhi, again)
print(dlo)
print((dhi * public_e) % totient)
```

and I receive the following output:

```
636240464814023378764909992533511921923019356298800552759060998545245874557680736027996744439605744391499043104720880636223885484565931958075694114602969603772836953480378611033860570300145043631854655856301042567276688120471797049369867521850989394897431415466979867779869180345783612977394922518330828854940313
[636240464814023378764909992533511921923019356298800552759060998545245874557680736027996744439605744391499043104720880636223885484565931958075694114602969603772836953480378611033860570300145043631854655856301042567276688120471797049369867521850989394897431415466979867779869180345783612977394922518330828854940313, -238103708533421475714858896671336507312403875131862901184693754748013912334601932203636671553039998644503980019560932552135687627136766643078437570437231059099895659568583992093120292787859671911875777353751983082813779209160246124430925687096691584151503946247340608480506316932401174615618781447863228050565478, 1]
636240464814023378764909992533511921923019356298800552759060998545245874557680736027996744439605744391499043104720880636223885484565931958075694114602969603772836953480378611033860570300145043631854655856301042567276688120471797049369867521850989394897431415466979867779869180345783612977394922518330828854940313
150745392025344981540220655009707296114649013040161319693843305709342759954667323742718447565889975961493119911431752682803859661147933598602890496951985277009912097242372921371628267709750248626347609462149819168991531633718687031590124254613925712131170620389455648853671942217723961481852728839231173169102228
1562407984278594326929432340506396048504926286142709897457913571627907981685740535815774238696826110015832751381955012607637021169488672911801969817887572128237305356644797429664070781240382537200981386696405591415076976090363032679326922345313657388984738122754200380778222205222301083144141308280991256883386454
1
```

(No need to look at the whole numbers)
So the first line and third line of the output are the same- which is good (I defined to functions two find the multiplicative inverse of public_e). I encrypted the text ('enc' in the code and line 4 in the output). The PROBLEM I'm having is when I decode it ('dlo' in the code and line 5 in the output) I don't get back my original number (which is a = 97). I checked in my code, and I am positive the gcd of my public_e and totient is 1, the product and totient values are correct, and as you can see from the last line of the output, 'dhi' really is the multiplicative inverse of public_e.

Any ideas?? I'm really stumped.

Comment: Can you give us enough code so that we can reproduce? In particular, the values of `prime_1`, `prime_2` and `public_e` would be helpful. Oh, and `totient`, too.

Comment: And are you sure that `prime_1` and `prime_2` are primes?

Comment: I resolved the issue- I think you were correct Mark I just rewrote the primality test and it worked. Thank you for the help!